# Javascript closures function parameters?

Tags: javascript, closures

Code belongs to javascriptissexy.com
My question is why invoking mjName ("Jackson") returns "This celebrity is Michael Jackson"?
Is it that second parameter given in ANY outer function always, says to js = inner function parameter? 
Could someone explain the whole concept in great detail?

```
function celebrityName (firstName) {
    var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
// this inner function has access to the outer function's variables, including the parameter
    function lastName (theLastName) {
        return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
    }
    return lastName;
}

var mjName = celebrityName ("Michael");
    // At this juncture, the celebrityName outer function has returned.

// The closure (lastName) is called here after the outer function has returned above
// Yet, the closure still has access to the outer function's variables and parameter
mjName ("Jackson"); // This celebrity is Michael Jackson
```

Comment: Every JavaScript function has access to variables defined in the same or higher scope. *"Is it that second parameter given in ANY outer function always, says to js = inner function parameter?"* I don't know what that's supposed to mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function is evaluated to be `celebrityName ("Michael")("Jackson");`

Steps :

1. celebrityName ("Michael") returns function lastName(theLastName)
2. ("Jackson") is passed to function lastName
3. function lastName(theLastName) prints the string when executed

Arguments from left to right go from outer to inner called methods.

Answer (score 19):

The OP asked for an explanation of the Whole concept in detail.  The attempt here is to describe the core elements that are necessary for closures to occur.

I think that part of the confusion with examples like the one from javascriptissexy is that the names of these functions do not clearly represent what they are supposed to do, especially to someone who is new to javascript or new coding in general.

#### Lets start by talking about scope:

In Javascript, every function creates its own local scope or memory space. This is called Lexical Scoping.  This memory space stores all of the variables from the functions's parameters as well as the declared variables and expressions within the function body (inside the curly braces).

As seen in the example from javascriptissexy, we can nest functions. Since each function creates its own local scope, we need to understand how these scopes relate and interact with each other.  There are three different types of relationships that scopes can have.

**I would encourage you to test all of these code snippets inside your browser dev console:**

#### Child scopes have access to their parent's (and grandparent's, great grandparent's etc...) scope variables

```
    function parent() {

        var parentAsset = 'The Minivan'

        function child() {

            //child has access to parent asset

            console.log(parentAsset);

        }

        // call child function

        child();
    }

    parent();  // 'The Minivan'
```

#### Parent scopes DO NOT have access to their children's scope variables

```
    function parent() {

        function child() {

            var childAsset = 'Mp3 Player'

        }

        //parent can't get childAsset

        console.log(childAsset);

    }

    parent();   // ReferenceError childAsset not defined
```

#### Sibling scopes DO NOT have access to each other's scope variables

```
    function childOne() {

        var childOneAsset = 'Iphone'

    }

    function childTwo() {

        console.log(childOneAsset);

    }

    childTwo();  // ReferenceError childOneAsset not defined
```

Okay, so back to the function mentioned by OP.  Let's try to remake this function with better names.  I am adding one more variable to this first example function to show a point.

#### Here are 4 things that happen when you call `getFirstName('Michael')`  in the example below:

1. Within this function,  the variable `firstName` is set to
   'Michael'
2. var `nameIntro` is set it to the value "This celebrity
   is "
3. var `unusedString` is set to the value "This string will be garbage collected"
4. The function `introduceCelebrity` is declared
5. The function `introduceCelebrity` is returned

   ```
   function getFirstName (firstName) {

       var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
       var unusedString = "This string will be garbage collected";

       function introduceCelebrity (lastName) {
           return nameIntro + firstName + " " + lastName;
       }

       return introduceCelebrity;
   }

   var mjName = getFirstName('Michael');
   ```

You probably already knew that.

#### Here are some interesting things to note:

- The `getFirstName` function does nothing with `firstName` or `nameIntro` other than set their values.  So there is no magic there.
- The child function `introduceCelebrity`  references those two variables. As mentioned before, it can do that because children scopes can access parent scope variables. This is the first important step to a closure.
- The `introduceCelebrity` function is then returned (but not executed), presumably so we can call it at a later time.  This is the second step to a closure.
- Because `introduceCelebrity` references parent scope variables, and we return the whole function, the javascript runtime maintains a pointer to those variables, even after the `getFirstName` function returns.
- Because that pointer exists, the garbage collector leaves those variables alone.  If those pointers didn't exist, the garbage collector would come through and clean those memory addresses and those values would be inaccessible.
- The `unusedString` variable is not referenced in the child function, therefore it is garbage collected and is no longer available.

So let's look at the code again:

```
function getFirstName (firstName) {

    var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";

    function introduceCelebrity (theLastName) {
        return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
    }
    return introduceCelebrity;
}

var mjName = getFirstName('Michael');
```

**When this code executes, we are basically doing this:**

```
var mjName = function(theLastName) {
    return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
}
```

**What is special about this?  Where is the closure?**

Because our `getFirstName` function has been executed, we might think that the whole thing has gone away along with its local variables or assets.  **THIS IS INCORRECT**.

We created a closure by referencing parent scope variables inside a child function and returning the child function.  So really, the new scope of the code right above actually looks more like this:

```
var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";

var firstName = "Michael"

var mjName = function(theLastName) {
    return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
}
```

See how `nameIntro` and `firstName` are now available to us?  **THAT IS BECAUSE WE CREATED CLOSURE**.

So now we call `mjName`:

```
mjName('Jackson');  // 'This celebrity is Michael Jackson'
```

And we get the result expected.

#### Wait, One last thing!

To really drive the point home, lets compare our example to a slightly modified one.

Notice the original function is nested.  **Closures only happen with nested functions**.

```
function getFirstName (firstName) {

    var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";

    function introduceCelebrity (theLastName) {
        return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
    }
    return introduceCelebrity;
}

var mjName = getFirstName('Michael');
```

Let's try removing that nesting:

```
function getFirstName (firstName) { 
    var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
}

function introduceCelebrity (theLastName) {
    return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
}

var mjName = getFirstName('Michael');
introduceCelebrity('Jackson');  

// ReferenceError: nameIntro is not defined
```

**Would this work?**

No, it wouldn't.  Because sibling scopes can't access each other's variables.

**How could we get this to work without a closure then?**

1. `getFirstName` must return an object or array with our variables
2. we must set `getFirstName('Michael')` to a global variable `mjName`
3. Call `introduceCelebrity('Jackon')`, passing in the values we `mjName`

   ```
   function getFirstName (firstName) { 

       var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";

       return {
           firstName: firstName,
           nameIntro: nameIntro
       }
   }

   var mjName = getFirstName('Michael');  // returns our object

   function introduceCelebrity (theLastName, firstName, nameIntro) {
       return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
   }

   introduceCelebrity('Jackson', mjName.firstName, mjName.nameIntro);  

   // 'This celebrity is Michael Jackson'
   ```

Comment: What if var nameIntro = "This celebrity is "; was a global object (outside outer function scope) like var nameIntro = ["This celebrity is "] , and we changed this array to ["Celebrity is "] before mjName('Jackson') call, why is the console still printing *This celebrity is* instead of 'Celebrity is' ?? Objects are passed by reference, so function argument should reflect the change. Could you please explain this also???

Answer (score 1):

With this call

```
var mjName = celebrityName ("Michael");
```

you create a custom function, which has the `firstName` variable bound to `"Michael"`. This function is returned to you by `celebrityName()`.

When you call that returned function again, you bind `lastName` as well, which results in your output.

If you want to bind another first name, you have to call `celebrityName()` again.

```
var michaelName = celebrityName( "Michael" );
var davidName =   celebrityName( "David" );

michaelName( "Jackson" ); // yields "This celebrity is Michael Jackson"
davidName( "Duchovny" );  // yields "This celebrity is David Duchovny"
```

Comment: So @Sirko: 1st time entered parameter relates to outer function. 2nd time entered parameter is inner function parameter. Calling celebrityName() twice binds outer and inner function(in that order)?

Comment: @user2067358 Calling `celebrityName()` just binds `firstName` to the returned function. The second parameter is bound, when this returned function is called.