# JS Closure and Function Parameters

Tags: javascript, closures

The following snippet is from "Example 5" from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) thread on JS and closure. Alternatively, [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655275/javascript-closures-function-parameters) sort of gets at what I'm curious about.

```
function buildList(list) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var item = 'item' + i;
        result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
    }
    return result;
}

function testList() {
    var fnlist = buildList([1,2,3]);
    for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
        fnlist[j]();
    }
}
```

The thread this snippet is from says the output is: "item3 undefined"x3. I understand why "item3" is printed all three times, but I don't understand why `list[i]` is undefined.

My Question: since list is a parameter of buildList, does that mean it's not a part of the closure of the anonymous function within result.push? If there were a variable within buildList (otherList) which was set to list (and the anonymous function used otherList[i]), would otherList[i] be in the closure? (Therefore instead of "item3 undefined"x3, the output would be "item3 3"x3).

Comment: It's not the list that's making it do that--it's the value of `i`. Actually, if you understand why `"item3"` is printed all three times, you understand why `list[3]` is `undefined`. So I suspect you actually don't ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: In fact it does alert `item2` three times.

Comment: I mistook 3 for the final index (2) because i was too bogged down in figuring out closure to "do the math" on the loop. Lesson learned. Although i still would have wondered my question.

Answer (score 0):

It has three elements, so maximum valid index is 2. So it is not printing `item3 undefined` it is `item2 undefined`.

**Reason :**

Since you know that the function is printing `item-2` string each time because, the function was bounded to the reference, not the value. (This can be avoided using Immediate invoking functions).

**But the loop stops/halts, when i cross the `i < array.length`**, So the last updated value of i is now `3` and array[1, 2, 3] at index 3 is `undefined`. Hence you are seeing undefined value.

---

**Verification:**

add console.log as shown below

```
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var item = 'item' + i;
        result.push( function() {
             console.log(i);              //Prints 3 for all 3 invocation.
             alert(item + ' ' + list[i])
        } );
    }
```

Comment: I understand. Does this mean function parameters are in fact able to be part of a closure?

Comment: Yes. That is how you can access `list` parameter in `function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])}` is accessible. Just try making `list.length` to `list.length - 1` you may get more clarity. (but the result is not the same, just to play around to understand better).